# pyqt4 Clicked on a checkbox when clicking a space other than the checkbox space

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I made QTreeWidget. And added checkbox in the list.
So, I made below code. (self.tableView is just empty box)

```
self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.tableView)
self.tree.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 131))

self.tree.headerItem().setText(0, "No")
self.tree.headerItem().setText(1, "Header")

self.checkList = []

for i in range(0, len(header)):
    self.checkList.append(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree))
    self.checkList[i].setText(0, "{}".format(str(i+1)))
    self.checkList[i].setText(1, "{}".format(header[i]).decode("utf-8"))
    self.checkList[i].setFlags(self.checkList[i].flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    self.checkList[i].setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
self.tree.show()
```

[image]

It is only checked if I click the checkbox space. (
It's a circle inside the picture.)
I want to be checked by clicking anywhere in the line.(It's a arrow inside the picture.) What do I have to? Please help me.

=========================================================================

As your answers I adjusted but it shows a bug.

```
def bringColumn(self):
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.tableView)
        self.tree.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 131))

        self.tree.headerItem().setText(0, "No")
        self.tree.headerItem().setText(1, "Header")
        # I added below code.
        self.tree.itemClicked.connect(self.onItemClicked)

def onItemClicked(self, item):
    item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if item.checkState(0) == QtCore.Qt.Checked else QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

[image]

Red circle part is not working. not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must connect the clicked signal, this returns the item and the column pressed, we will use the item and the setChecked method

```
    self.tree.itemClicked.connect(self.onItemClicked)

def onItemClicked(self, item, column):
    item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if item.checkState(0) == QtCore.Qt.Checked else QtCore.Qt.Checked )
```

Comment: I have a problem. When I adjusted this as I click the checkbox button is not working. Only clicking other space except checkbox spaces is work. I think events are cracked. Please help.

Comment: Create a question by showing your code and pointing out your error or error message, please make the code comply with be [mcve]

Comment: @Layla I do not understand why I dismiss this answer as correct, explain it to me please.

Comment: I uploaded please check it.

Comment: I think that events are collide.

Comment: @Layla Yes, I just checked, the problem is that by default it is changing, and then we are changing it with the code, I am seeing how to avoid duplicity.

Comment: Did you check it?